# In SonarQube, when the cppcheck-report.xml is empty, it gives error

Tags: c++, sonarqube, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

While running the plugin for C++, when the cppcheck-report.xml does not contain any data (blank file generated from cpp-check due to parser error), SonarQube is complaining exception

```
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to parse file: cppcheck-report.xml    at com.sonar.cpp.plugin.C.A.A(Unknown Source)   at com.sonar.cpp.plugin.C.D.analyse(Unknown Source)     at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)  at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:119)     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:194)  at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
```

How can we overcome this?

Comment: As it's a commercial plugin, you should contact the SonarSource support team. Thanks

Comment: You can reach the support [here](http://www.sonarqube.org/get-support/)